# How to change the tooltip background color

Tags: html

I wanted to create Similar tooltip as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Qv6L2/294/

(Please mouse over on the input fields to see the tooltip)

I was following the above fiddle and created my code as

```
<div class="kp-color-button">
   <a id="bullishengulfing" rel="tooltip"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="This is bullishengulfing" class="candlespattern green-button">Bullish Engulfing</a>
   <a id="dojiyestersay" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"  data-toggle="tooltip"  title="This is dojiyestersay" class="candlespattern orange-button">Doji Yesterday</a>
   <a id="hammer" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is hammer"  class="candlespattern light-blue-button">Hammer Pattern</a>
   <a id="bearishengulfing" data-placement="bottom"  data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" title="This is bearishengulfing" class="candlespattern maroon-button">Bearish Engulfing</a>
</div>
```

and this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7jf3E/31/

Could you please tell me how to create similar tooltip ??

Comment: I'm a bit confused - you seem to have answered the question before asking it!

Comment: sorry for the confusion created , in my fiddle its showing default tooltip , and i wanted it to make it appear as shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qv6L2/294/

Comment: I guess he want to achieve the same effect without the js plugins used in the first jsfiddle

Comment: i have used the plugins used by the prevous fiddle .

Comment: @PreethiJain Doesn't look like it from here - There is only one CSS file on your fiddle, no JS

Comment: @PreethiJain and there is no JS in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The first fiddle uses a set of JS and CSS code to create tooltips.

In the code you are using in the second fiddle, the tooltips are based on the "title" HTML attribute and all the data-* stuff you added have no effect.

EDIT: to be more specific, a "title"-based tooltip is generated by the browser, like a tooltip in an application. It is not an HTML entity and thus cannot be styled.

It seems that you've copied/pasted these data attributes form some other code/page without knowing excatly what they are. Perhaps something using Bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Anyway, to answer your question, you cannot change the color for "title"-based tooltip.

But do not hesitate to check Bootstrap if you are starting a new website.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

First add another `div` for the tooltip

```
<div id = "tooltip"></div>
```

then hide it with CSS

```
#tooltip {
    display: none;
}
```

then use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bullishengulfing").hover(function() {
        $("#tooltip").show("slow");
        $("#tooltip).text("the text for that category");
    )}; // repeat this for every div
)};
```

hope this helps!

Comment: thnak you , i have done the same , but its not working http://jsfiddle.net/7jf3E/34/

Comment: did you add the jQuery CDN?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>